# Android inter-activity communication

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I am a total android newbie so my question might seem dumb.

I want to make a program that has two activities, one of them is TinyCalActivity1 and the other is TinyCalActivity2.

My intention was that I can make a button to switch between this activity,

```
package my.app.tinyCal;

    public class TinyCalActivity1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button myButton;
    EditText myEdit;
    //Intent i = new Intent(TinyCalActivity1.this, TinyCalActivity2.class);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
        myEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);
        CharSequence thisNum = "1234565";
        myEdit.setText(thisNum);

        OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
            }
        };

        myButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
    }
}
```

and TinyCalActivity2.

However, when I write this line and run in my android AVD, it tells me that there's an error.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TinyCalActivity2.class);
```

There is no error hint in eclipse and I do not know why. 
I create TinyCalActivity2.java as a separate file in the same folder as my TinyCalActivity1.java file. And I have registered TinyCalActivity2 in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: put the error log up. it will give everyone an idea of whats going wrong.

Comment: use logcat to see what the runtime error acutally is

Comment: Yes I should have looked at the error log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your code

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TinyCalActivity2.class);
```

in button click event, then `this` refers to button and not ACTIVITY. Thus, you need to mention it as

```
Intent i = new Intent(TinyCalActivity1.this, TinyCalActivity2.class);
```

This may resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, TinyCalActivity2.class);
            finish();
            }
        };
```